# Flexbox centering items is causing overlapping content

Tags: css, flexbox

When I try to use flexbox to center items there is some overlapping content and misalignment.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/a9oc6gL8/1/

```
.footer_3 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 220px;
     padding-bottom:100px;
}

.footer_4 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 190px;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `align-items: top`? (which is not a valid rule)

Comment: @Michael_B I used that so that the say 01 and 02 will be aligned together from the top as does 03 and 04 together.

Comment: Then you may be looking for `align-items: flex-start`. [Revised Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a9oc6gL8/3/)

Comment: @Michael_B There's still misalignment when you look at  03 and 04. They're not aligned together. Is this because I only specified `max-width` for `about_description`? When I just a static width like 800px, they align but then aren't sitting in the center of the page.

Comment: You've got lots of positioning, padding and flex alignment going on. You don't need that many rules. I posted an answer with a simple starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain, I've drawn some extra rectangles to demonstrate what goes wrong.

[image: overlapping stuff]

The top-left and top-right columns together are as wide as the bottom-left and bottom-right bar, but are not the same ratio.

Now I could go and explain how to fix this, but I've noticed that you've been making a lot of mistakes throughout the document. I think it's more important that you try to get a little better at the basics, than trying the get the hang of flexbox.

Besides that. I've created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9oc6gL8/7/) that shows a fixed situation. I've given it a complete overhaul without `flexbox`.

What I've done, is create two columns that are both exactly 50% wide. They both float to the left. Like this, the text of the left and right side are always at the same spot. I've cleaned up the code (you were switching `ul` and `li`, using unnecessary classes, you used a plain ampersand (`&`) whilst you should type `&amp;` when creating one... There was a lot wrong). Also. The '01', '02' etc. are now automatically generated with CSS.

The document has changed as a whole. I advise looking into it, and trying to understand what happens with every line of code. It'll sure teach you a thing or two.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code. With these adjustments, your desired alignments come together:

**CSS**

```
.footer_3 {
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 220px auto 50px;
}

.footer_4 {
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.about_description {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/a9oc6gL8/8/)